# Mod_evasive casuing trouble

Tags: apache2

After i changed one of my database tables into InoDB from myisam i started to get "client denied by server configuration:" in my error log. After finding out mod_evasive was the problem i added the following to the apache config file. After an apache restart still get the errors so i disabled "DOSHashTableSize" and no more errors came in the log after a restart of apache and 10 minutes waiting.

**example of error**:
Thu Mar 31 00:04:33.313448 2022] [:error] [pid 24921] [client 103.125.235.21:57710] client denied by server configuration: /home//public_html/raq.php

Anyone know what settings i should use on for mod_evasive ? the website is a quite high traffic one.

```
<IfModule mod_evasive.c>
        DOSHashTableSize 12289
        DOSPageCount 512
        DOSSiteCount 512
        DOSPageInterval 2
        DOSSiteInterval 10
        DOSBlockingPeriod 10
</IfModule>
```

Comment: *What* error messages do you see in the log file?

Comment: i update my question